# 16F877 microcontroller memory size 8k

Tags: microcontroller, microchip

16F877  microcontroller memory size is 8k(8192 X 14 bits)
8192 derived from , 1k = 1024 byte
            so,     8k= 1024 X 8 = 8192   its  clear for me..
   but what is 14 bits  and why is multiplied  with 8192    please explain...

Comment: hello  sir,   but i m asking my question related to microchip programming  and its theory.  i dont understande why is is off topic...

Answer (score 1):

The 16F877 has 14 bit wide instructions. Therefore 8192 X 14 bits refers to having 8192 instructions each of which take up 14 bits.

Comment: 8192 is total no. of memory allocation  or   total instruction?

Comment: @sumit Total instruction. It has only 368 bytes (yes, less than 0.5k) of RAM and 256 bytes of EEPROM (think of it as a tiny flash drive)

Answer (score 0):

Microchip is counting the flash memory of the PIC16 family in words (one word is 14 Bit wide).
But they are counting the memory of the PIC18, PIC24 and PIC 32 family in Bytes. So you had to pay attention if you want to compare the memory of the different families.

Comment: i m thinking abt  memory of 16F877 is that its memory size 8k  as mentioned in data sheet so is has 8 X 1024 = 8192 memory allocations and each memory allocation save only 14 bit  .. plzz   tell me am i right??????

Comment: Yes, you're right for a PIC16

Comment: thanx  dear for clearification...